# Zoom in to cut out white space on phone

Tags: html, css

I understand responsive design to some degree but im trying to build an email template that will work well on all platforms it is viewed on. The jsfiddle i have included is the idea im working off of. How can i make it so my margins work more % based. I dont like the idea of them being % base because then it looks huge on the desktop and tiny on the phone. Any way i can allow my margin auto to fit better to the window?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="copyright" content="Copyright 2013 AAM Group.." />
<meta name="description" content="None" />
<title>NewsWire - Template</title>

<style>
    #wrapper { margin: 0 auto; width: 600px; }
    #subject { background-color: #CCCCCC; float: left; margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 5px; width: 285px;  } 
    #viewBrowser { background-color: #CCCCCC; float: left; margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 5px; text-align: right; width: 285px;  } 
    #header { background-color: #CCCCCC; float: left; height: 75px; margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 5px; width: 425px; }
    #date { background-color: #CCCCCC; float: left; height: 75px; margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 5px; width: 150px; }
    #heroUnit { background-color: #CCCCCC; float: left; height: 225px; margin-bottom: 5px; width: 600px; } 
    #rightBlock { background-color: #CCCCCC; float: left; height: 315px; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: -165px; padding: 5px; width: 150px; } 
    #lowerRightBlock { background-color: #CCCCCC; float: left; height: 150px; margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 5px; width: 150px; }
    #banners { background-color: #CCCCCC; float: left; height: 75px; margin-bottom: 5px; width: 600px; }
    #footer { background-color: #CCCCCC; float: left; height: 75px; margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 5px; width: 590px;  }

    .content { background-color: #CCCCCC; float: left; height: 150px; margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; padding: 5px; width: 425px; } 
    .roundCorners { border-radius: 5px; }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="subject" class="roundCorners">Subject Line</div>
    <div id="viewBrowser" class="roundCorners">View in Browser</div>

    <div id="header" class="roundCorners">Header</div>
    <div id="date" class="roundCorners">Date</div>

    <div id="heroUnit" class="roundCorners">Hero Unit</div>

    <div class="content roundCorners">Content Block</div>
    <div class="content roundCorners">Content Block</div>
    <div id="rightBlock" class="roundCorners">Content Right Block</div>

    <div class="content roundCorners">Content Block</div>  
    <div id="lowerRightBlock" class="roundCorners">Lower Right Content Block</div>  

    <div id="banners" class="roundCorners">Banners</div>

    <div id="footer" class="roundCorners">Footer</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pw3kV/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is hugely opinion-based, but OK. You can give the `body` a padding in pixels and the wrapper a padding in percents, and then tinker with the relative amounts until they come out the way you want.

For instance if you only have a 2% padding on the wrapper, then it will be 38 pixels on a big screen, 6 pixels on a tiny one. But if you have 10 pixels on the body plus 1% on the wrapper, then it will be 29 pixels on the big screen and 13 pixels on the tiny one.